# iAd notification *const__strong' to parameter of

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, iad

I am introducing iAd on my app like previous but now, when adView.delegate = self, a notification is showed. Why? code seems to be like always with property and synthezise and also runs properly. Notification showed: "Passing 'ViewController *const__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id". Thank you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    //iAd

    adView =[[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil];

    adView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:adView];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify that the ViewDelegate conforms to the protocol `ADBannerViewDelegate`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
//...
@end
```